# Can a ring that is not finitely generated and contains $\mathbb{C}$ be Noetherian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose we have a ring R that contains the complex numbers, $\mathbb{C}\subset R$ and is **not** finitely generated *as a ring*. Can R be Noetherian?

Comment: When you say that $R$ is not finitely generated as a ring, do you refer that it is not finitely generated as a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra? Or do you refer to other notion of finitely generated?

Comment: I mean finitely generated as $\mathbb{C}$-algebra.

Comment: @user121097: That link seems to be a situation involving finitely generated as a module, rather than as an algebra.  However it is relatively easy to give an example where $R$ is a field, and so trivially Noetherian.

Comment: That's right. Any field extension of $C$ with infinite field extension degree works. If you allow localization, then you might be interested in an example by Nagata. It is an infinite dimensional Noetherian ring constructed from $\mathbb{C}[$many variables$]$.

Comment: @user121097: I'm sorry I doubted you. You are correct about the ring being f.g. as an algebra in that post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathbb{C} (x)$ be the field of rational functions in one variable. Then $\mathbb{C} (x)$ contains $\mathbb{C}$, is not finitely generated as a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra (let alone as a ring), and is noetherian.